# iOS / iPhone - Hide status bar when UIActivityViewController is displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

My app keeps status bar hidden and I am using a UIActivityViewController for sharing links in
one of my app views.

When the UIActivityViewController is presented, the status bar is shown at first. After the user interacts with the UIActivityViewController (ie. by choosing message or something), the status bar hides but I need it to be hidden from the beginning.

How do I stop UIActivityViewController from showing the status bar upon presentation?

Code:

```
- (void)openActionSheet {



NSString *shareString = @"link";

NSArray *shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:shareString];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypeAirDrop, nil];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)openActionSheet {

NSString *shareString = @"link";

NSArray *shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:shareString];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypeAirDrop, nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

just hide status bar before presenting activityController.

Comment: what is happening in this state.

Comment: Same problem, status bar is showing when the UIActivityViewController is presented

Comment: [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.5]]; add this line after setStatusBarHidden and wait for half sec and then presentViewController.

Answer (score 0):

set View controller-based status bar appearance value in your .plist file.

like this.[image]

Now use below method to show status bar or not. //just you have to add this method in your view-controller **this will call automatically**

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

This will surly working.

Comment: I already have prefersStatusBarHidden and set View controller-based status bar appearance set this way and it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as subclassing UIActivityViewController and setting prefersStatusBarHidden to true. Swift code:

```
// Subclass of UIActivity view controller that keeps the status bar hidden.
class MyUIActivityViewController : UIActivityViewController
{
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: For Swift 3 this should be:
`
  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
  }
`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 1.1 answer:**

To hide the status bar when presenting the UIActivityViewController:

1. Ensure that in the .plist file, the key "View controller-based status bar appearance” boolean is set to “YES”.
2. Add the following code:

> extension UIActivityViewController {
>
> override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
>
> self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
>
> }
>
> override public func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
>
> return true
>
> }
>
> }

*Worth noting, I had only experienced status bar issues when displaying UIActivityViewController running iOS 7.1 simulator. Didn't seem to experience an issue with iOS 8.1 simulator.*